# How to delete the content of an input bar after sending this content?

Tags: javascript, solid-js

I created a chat application in solid-js. However when a user sends a message from the
chat input bar, the message is not automatically cleared from the bar after sending. So that the content
from the input bar to be cleared automatically after sending a message, I wrote the following code:

```
 <input
              type="text"
              name="content"
              id="content"
              value={content()}
              onInput={(e) => setContent(e.currentTarget.value)}
            />

            . . .

            <Show when={content().trim().length}>
              <button
                onClick={() =>{
                 content().trim().length==null
                }
                }
              >
                <BiSolidSend />
              </button>
            </Show>
```

But that didn't work, so I changed my code to:

```
<button
  onClick={() =>{
                delete content()
                }
                }
>
```

But it still didn't work. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setContent` to make it an empty string instead of using the `delete` keyword:

```
<button onClick={()=>{setContent("")}}>
    Button
</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? I can't reproduce what you're talking about. Here's the code I'm running:

```js
function TextDemo() {
  const [text, setText] = createSignal("");
  const clear = () => setText("");

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={clear}>
        Clear
      </button>
      <input value={text()} onInput={(e) => setText(e.currentTarget.value)}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your example works perfectly, I was doing something wrong on my side. Stackoverflow locked my downvote and won't let me remove it unless the answer is edited. If you do a tiny edit to it, I will upvote it. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Did a small edit, sorry for the trouble!